# is there a way to configure DBT to not drop the tables?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, snowflake-time-travel

Using DBT and Snowflake, as far as I can see regular/non-incremental models are not snowflake Time travel enabled, I guess it's because DBT uses create or replace, is there a way to configure DBT to do something else (truncate and insert for instance) so that these tables will work with Snowflake time travel?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, modify `dbt_projects.yml`. Use `+materialized: insert_overwrite`.

```
models:
  myfolder:
    +query_tag: dbt
  # Config indicated by + and applies to all files under models/example/
    my_prod_schema: 
      +materialized: insert_overwrite
```

Comment: according to docs dbt-snowflake does not support that, but  I'll try